# Shared Preference data not cleared when activity is closed

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

in my application, I used place picker.and data that place picker gave is sent to 3 different activities using shared preference.and show this data in TextView.problem is when I closed activity and again open that activity my data still visible in TextView.even when I cleared it in `onDestroy()`.

**here is my code for send data from place picker:**

```
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("city_address", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("city_address", (String) cityAddress);
            editor.putString("city_name", (String) city);
            editor.commit();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CleanlinessActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

**set data using this code in  onCreate() of CleanlinessActivity**

```
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("city_address", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String n = settings.getString("city_name", "Enter Location");
    String a = settings.getString("city_address", "");
    cityname.setText(n);
    cetlocation.setText(a);
```

**and i cleared data using this code in CleanlinessActivity**

```
     @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("city_address", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.remove("city_address");
    editor.clear().commit();
}
```

Comment: You should not do this in `onDestroy()` . `onDestroy()` is not meant to call each time . Also use a single `SharedPreferences` there is no need to use two of them . And for your answer `editor.clear().commit();` will do the job .

Comment: post the complete activity code

Comment: seems like the issue is , your first code is inserting data and it is being executed the moment you start your app

Comment: test case: try calling `super.onDestroy()` later cause sharedPrefs use different thread...till it gets executed properly may be the context gets cleared !! update if it works !! i will post the answer ! `editor.clear().commit(); super.onDestroy();`

Comment: not working @santanu

Comment: how do you know the values persist , in the first place ?? did you log or debug ??

Comment: because `.apply()` should work fine !!

Comment: I have textview to show the values.

Comment: Actually, it worked fine for the first time and probably stop working.

Comment: If you intend to remove the value in `onDestroy`, why would you want to keep it in `SharedPreferences` instead of class variable?

Comment: I don't know how but now it's working perfectly with my code.i did not do anything with my code.LOL

Answer (score 0):

By closing the app you mean just clicking the home button then `onDestroy()` is never called, you can get a refresher of the android life cycles [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) 
If what you are doing is simply clicking the home button then consider moving your code to the `onStop()` otherwise you need to `commit()` following the `remove(...)` The android documentation states "Mark in the editor that a preference value should be removed, which will be done in the actual preferences once commit() is called."

Answer (score 0):

You have an instance of SharedPreferences called city_address which is having two fields or (Columns if we call it),but inside `onDestroy()`you are trying to to clear only one field of it called city_address,and the other field city_name field is left unchanged,if you want to completely remove the content of the city_address SharedPreferences use `editor.clear().commit();` 
  or``editor.clear().apply();`